# SSRS remove repeating group rows

Tags: reporting-services, hide, repeat

In SSRS I have a table where the group rows can sometime repeat themselves (This is normal as I group them by chronological order not by themsevles).
What I can't do is remove just the label.

what I've been able to do so far is remove the whole group but I don't want to do that as I need the information inside the group. (this can by done by the visibility property of the group property OR by the tablix property of the whole row).

Also, I am able to hide all group headers when I put visibility hidden as true.

I tried using an expression, namely some version of this expression

```
=iif(Fields!YourField.Value = Previous(Fields!YourField.Value), True, False)
```

however this doesn't work as i'm selecting a group and this only works when you're in the detail area of the report not in the group. so I have to find the equivalent for Fields!YourField.Value but for a group header.

I also tried using the property HideDuplicate in the Other section however no mater what value I enter it gives me an error that is very similar to the other one, that because I'm applying a property to a group I have to select a group. I tried placing the group name but to no avail.

so to give an example of what I'm trying to do : say I have a table such as :

```
**OPERATION 1**
action 1 time a
action 7 time b
action 3 time c
**OPERATION 2**
action 4 time d
action 2 time e
action 5 time f
**OPERATION 2**
action 1 time g
action 9 time h
action 2 time i
**OPERATION 1**
action 2 time j
action 3 time k
action 4 time l

and what I would like would be something like this :

**OPERATION 1**
action 1 time a
action 7 time b
action 3 time c
**OPERATION 2**
action 4 time d
action 2 time e
action 5 time f
action 1 time g
action 9 time h
action 2 time i
**OPERATION 1**
action 2 time j
action 3 time k
action 4 time l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use group headers because you are not really grouping. Create another `Detail` row above your current detail row and format this like your group header. Now you can use your expression on the `Visibility`-`Hidden` property on this new detail "header row":

```
=iif(Fields!YourField.Value = Previous(Fields!YourField.Value), True, False)
```

This will cause the "header row" to only display when the operation value changes.

Comment: I am grouping the data, it's just that I'm putting the group as a row, the raw data looks like this : 
operation 1, action 1, time a  --  
operation 1, action 7, time b  --  
operation 1, action 3, time c  --  
operation 2, action 4, time d  --  
etc...

Comment: Unless you are using aggregate functions like `SUM` and `COUNT` you can do it my way.

Comment: perhaps but the actual report has 3 subgroups beneath every operation, so in actuality it looks like this :
`**OPERATION 1**`
`*sub1 1*`
`sub2 1`
`sub3 1`
`action 1 time a`
`action 7 time b`
`action 3 time c`
so remouving it outside the group could be possible but would be hell to handle every hidden column

Comment: on second thought perhaps not, let me give it a try

Comment: yep, it worked, thanks. it was a lot of rows that I had to configure the visibility on. however had I had a sum or a count what would have been your suggestion?

Comment: I would have configured something using custom code. However, I wasn't sure of the execution order of the code within the group header so I would have needed to test that first.